# How to prevent CodeIgniter from creating a session for every visit?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, tankauth

I am using sessions saved to database and TankAuth in CodeIgniter 2.1.3.
The overall setup is that TankAuth checks to see if the user is logged in via

```
$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()
```

This refers to libraries/Tank_auth.php

```
function is_logged_in($activated = TRUE)
{
    return $this->ci->session->userdata('status') === ($activated ? STATUS_ACTIVATED : STATUS_NOT_ACTIVATED);
}
```

which requires the session class to be initialized -- which will then create a new session in the database.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to circumvent this, because my database is getting filled with empty sessions for non-logged-in users.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that you can do for removing the NON ACTIVE SESSIONS:-

1. every time whenever a user is logged out, remove its row from the DB and call the session destroy function like

   $this->CI->DB_Master->where('session_id', $session['session_id']);
   $this->CI->DB_Master->delete($this->session_table);
   $this->sess_destroy();
2. Run a cron job, to run after every specific interval of time based on your DB data, To remove the rows corresponding to the NON ACTIVE Users.